# Is the word margarine used in as the same sense every English speaking country

Tags: word-choice, word-request, dialect

I'd like to ask if the word **margarine** is used in as the same sense as the following in English speaking countries like the USA , the UK, Canada etc. Are there any other words which can be used to define it?

> A butter substitute made from vegetable oils or animal fats.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarine#National_standards Looks like that is the case - the Wikipedia article doesn't note any different terms per country other than the very rare usage of "oleo" in the US... generally limited to crossword puzzles.

Comment: [I Can't Believe It's Not Butter!®](https://www.unileverusa.com/brands/our-brands/i-cant-believe-its-not-butter.html), though I have never bought this one.

Comment: Moreover, it is used in the same meaning in some other languages because  it originated from Greek *margaron*.